# IE crashes on call to fadeOut

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-effects

Well as weird as it sounds it's that simple. i can't understand why but if i comment the fade in it dosen't crash and works perfectly.

Same result in IE 8 &9

When i say crash i mean i get the following message (Windows 7) :

```
Internet Explorer has stopped working, windows will look for solution
```

I don't think u want to see the entire code because there's alot of JS involved but the relevant part is :

```
$('#add_image_upload').fadeOut(1000, function(){
 }); // has some commented code inside
```

html :

```
    <div id="add_image_upload">
<form action="http://localhost/ci/index.php/do_upload" 
    method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <span id="fileinput_button_label">TEXT</span>
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="fileupload_input" multiple="">
     </form>
</div>
```

Anyone knows what could cause this? Could it be related to memory size because i do
alot of jQuery effects in this page?

Comment: u know in winows 7.. crash with the message : "Internet Explorer has stopped working, windows will look for solutions"

Comment: @bcoughlan Crashes I believe.

Comment: lol sorry for spelling mistake didn't notice

Comment: Have you tried putting the isolated code in a fiddle? You may be seeing a side-effect of another piece of code.

Comment: I most likley am seeing a side-effect as there's no reason fadeOut shouldn't work on IE, i just don't know what could crash it.

Comment: Try binary chopping through the effects. Disable half of the site/remove the script, does it fix it, if it does, re-enable half etc. You'll find it eventually that way. Either that or look in a good debugger to find out what's running at the same time as the fadeOut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently when outputing some HTML i forgot to add a / to the ending tag, and other browsers automatically corrected it so it worked but IE dosen't.

In case this happens make sure your HTML is valid.